# Browser caches HTTP site as HTTPS resulting in Cert Error when navigating from site to an HTTPS destination

Tags: http, https, cache-control, http-redirect

I have a company website that's hosted as https://foo.bar.com.

However, it was incorrectly conveyed to a lot of users that the URL would be www.foo.bar.com. Until this can be rectified, we are putting through an interim solution by setting up a proxy site www.foo.bar.com that will redirect any users coming to it to https://foo.bar.com.

This works... but only the first time the user navigates to the page. The next time I try to access www.foo.bar.com, due to caching, the browser takes me to https://www.foo.bar.com. We don't have a certificate set up for https://www.foo.bar.com and as a result are given a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error.

Is there a way to work around this without needing a certificate?

To test, I've even tried returning a webpage when the I navigate to www.foo.bar.com with a link that navigates to https://foo.bar.com. However, the same issue happens even in this case. I'm guessing HSTS is at play here but not sure how to go about it.

I'd appreciate any insight into this matter, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you not just get a certificate from [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for www.foo.bar.com?  How are you doing your initial redirect that is being cached?

Comment: @kicken If it has to be done with a certificate then we know the way forward. To work around the approvals process, we're trying to see if there's a way to proceed without having to rely on a certificate. I've tried redirects using window.location.replace and window.location.href when I navigate to www.foo.bar.com.

Comment: A valid certificate is the only way to fix NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

Comment: @kicken I understand that but I'm not sure why it only happens the second time onwards. The first time I hit www.foo.bar.com, it redirects me as intended to https:// foo.bar.com without any cert issues. I'm guessing it's because of HSTS, when the redirect is done, it caches "https:// www.foo.bar.com" instead of "http:// www.foo.bar.com". I'm guessing after the initial communication between the client and server, the browser sees the Strict-Policy-Security header and knows that it must save the URL with "https" instead of "http". If there's a way to override this behavior, that's what I'm after

Comment: After the first attempt, even if I try to manually navigate to "http:// www.foo.bar.com", the browser changes the "http" to "https".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive the only solution to your problem is to obtain a valid certificate for www.foo.bar.com.  Due to the certificate error the browsers will not attempt to communicate with your server so there's no way for you to issue a redirect away from wrong domain to the correct domain.

### Why only the second time?

You mention HSTS so I am assuming https://foo.bar.com is sending a Strict-Transport-Security header as part of it's response.  This header likely is being sent with the **includeSubDomains** option which instructs the browser to not only enforce HTTPS on foo.bar.com but also all subdomains of that main domain.  As a result, when trying to request www.foo.bar.com the browser matches that HSTS rule and automatically re-writes it to use HTTPS.

Once this HSTS rule has been set in the browser it cannot be removed except by expiring, either by exceeing the original max-age time or by issuing another Strict-transport-security header with **max-age=0** on https://foo.bar.com

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. I reached the same conclusion as well. Accepting this answer.